# Thinking of making an opensource iOS app, what should I put in my .gitingnore?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, gitignore

I also want to distribute it in the App Store. I want to put the XCode project and all source on github. Is there anything I should exclude from the repo to avoid exposing personally identifying information? For example the `.pbxuser` file and such?

I expect not, but I'd like to be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I put in mine:

```
build
.DS_Store
*.perspectivev3
*.pbxuser
*.xcworkspacedata
*.xcuserstate
```

I don't think there is any personal information besides your user name and maybe some file paths.